# More than one condition meet numpy select

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I hv the following dataframe:

```
     A   B  C  D   E   F
    100  0  0  0  100  0
     0  100 0  0   0  100
   -100  0  0  0  100  0
```

and this code:

```
cond = [
    (df['A'] == 100),
    (df['A'] == -100),
    (df['B'] == 100),
    (df['C'] == 100),
    (df['D'] == 100),
    (df['E'] == 100),
    (df['F'] == 100),
    ]
choices = ['A','neg_A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F']
df['result'] = np.select(cond, choices)
```

For both rows there will be two results but I want only one to be selected. I want the selection to be made with this criteria:

```
   +A = 67%
   -A = 68%
    B = 70%
    C = 75%
    D = 66%
    E = 54%
    F = 98%
```

Percentage shows accuracy rate so i would want the one with highest percentage to be preferred over the other.

Intended result:

```
    A   B  C  D   E   F   result
    100  0  0  0  100  0     A
     0  100 0  0   0  100    F
   -100  0  0  0  100  0    neg_A
```

Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

EDIT:

Some of the columns (like A) may have a mix of 100 and -100. Positive 100 will yield a simple A (see row 1) but a -100 should yield some other name like "neg_A" in the result (see row 3).

Answer (score 2):

Let's `sort` the columns of dataframe based on the `priority` values then use [`.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) + [`.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on `axis=1` to get the column name with first occurrence of `100`:

```
# define a dict with col names and priority values
d = {'A': .67, 'B': .70, 'C': .75, 'D': .66, 'E': .54, 'F': .98}

df['result'] = df[sorted(d, key=lambda x: -d[x])].eq(100).idxmax(axis=1)
```

---

```
     A    B  C  D    E    F result
0  100    0  0  0  100    0      A
1    0  100  0  0    0  100      F
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Some of the columns hv -100 in them. How do I take that into account?

Comment: @JoharInamUnnar So you would aslo like to compare these columns to `-100`?

Comment: Yeah, currently it's only looking for 100. I want it to also look for -100

Comment: @JoharInamUnnar You can use `.isin` in place of `eq` like `.isin([100, -100])`...alternatively you can take the `abs` value like `df[sorted(d, key=lambda x: -d[x])].abs().eq(100).idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: I gave it some thought and realized ur approach may not solve my problem. Is it possible that i can add the dictionary into my numpy.select approach since my problem requires me to write a custom name if the value of any column is negative. See the edit pls, i hv added another row with such circumstance.